# Can Forge Viewer SDK store files on its own server and open nwd files properly?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Problem description:

1: Can I store files on my own server instead of autodesk?

2: Take question 1: I found a repository on github where viewer-javascript-Offline-sample opens native files, some common 3D model files are fine, but when I opened the.nwd file I needed, Got this hint (The file extension loaded into the Viewer is not supported).

3: Answer question 2: But I found that the online preview demo provided by the official website can normally open the nwd file, and visual upload preview with vscode can also normally open the nwd file.

Expecting: The file is stored on its own server, and the nwd file can be opened normally.

-- Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.

Try: github ,google, official document, and so many demo.
Expecting: The file is stored on its own server, and the nwd file can be opened normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store your files wherever you want, but it has to be on our server **while** it's being translated to **SVF** (the **Viewer**'s format)
2. "opens native files" - if by "native" you mean **desktop app native** like **Revit**, **Inventor**, **AutoCAD**, then it's a misunderstanding. The **Viewer**'s own **native** format is **SVF**, and the only other formats it can open directly are: **PDF** and **DWF**/**DWFx**. The [sample you pointed to](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample)  is also loading **SVF** - see [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L24).
3. "official website" - whether it's **Fusion Team**, [Autodesk Viewer](https://viewer.autodesk.com/), or any other site, they as well first translate the file to **SVF** - that's the only way the **Viewer** can open e.g. a **Navisworks** file

Once you generated the **SVF** you could possibly [store it on your server](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs) and open it from there.